# Find the solution of the wave equation $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ with initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of the wave equation

$u_{tt} = u_{xx}$

for $0 < x < \pi$ with the boundary conditions:

$u = 0$ at $x = 0, \pi$

and the intitial conditions at $t = 0$

$u = 0$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = x$, $0 < x < \pi$

**My attempt: (using separation of variables solution)**

The boundary conditions in mathematical notation are:

(a) $u(0, t) = 0$
(b) $u(\pi, t) = 0$
(c) $u(x, 0) = 0$
(d) $u_t (x, 0) = x$

The basic solutions to the wave equation are:

$u_1 = cos(\lambda t) cos(\lambda x)$

$u_2 = cos(\lambda t) sin(\lambda x)$

$u_3 = sin(\lambda t) cos(\lambda x)$

$u_4 = sin(\lambda t) sin(\lambda x)$

Now, from condition (a), (b) we know $u(x,t)$ cannot = $u_1$ or $u_3$
from condition (c), we know $u(x,t)$ cannot = $u_2$

Therefore our solution is of the form:

$u(x,t) = sin(\lambda t) sin(\lambda x)$

Then we partially differentiate with respect to t and get:

$u_t (x, t) = \lambda cos(\lambda t) sin(\lambda x)$

so that, by condition (d)

$u_t (x,0) = x$ when ?

Here my mathematics breaks down so an error must have been made. If anyone could point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: What's the initial condition on $\partial u/\partial t$?

Comment: Sorry, edit was made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct so far, though you have forgotten an arbitrary constant $A$ with which your function can be multiplied - this will be important soon.

Note, first, that $\lambda$ must be an integer, which we take to be positive without loss of generality (as $\sin(x)$ is odd, $\sin(nx)\sin(nt)$ is even).

Thus, $u(x,t) = A\sin(nx)\sin(nt)$. Note, however, that this solves your PDE with all the boundary conditions and initial condition (c) - we'll consider the initial condition (d) in a moment - for any integer $n$ and any real number $A$, thus we may write our solution as a linear combination in the following manner:

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(nx)\sin(nt)$$

Differentiating this with respect to $t$, we get

$$u_t(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin(nx)\cos(nt)$$

where $B_n := nA_n$.

Thus, by initial condition (d):

$$u_t(x, 0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin(nx) = x$$

This is a Fourier Sine series expansion, which we want to be equal to a given function - this means that we must determine the coefficients $B_n$, which are given by the following integral:

\begin{align*}B_n &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}x\sin(nx)dx\\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{x\cos(nx)}{n}\right]_0^\pi + \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(nx)dx \\
&= -2\frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right]_0^\pi \\
&= 2\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\end{align*}

Thus, we have satisfying initial condition (d):

$$u_t(x, t) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx)\cos(nt)$$

Now recall that $B_n = nA_n \Rightarrow A_n = \frac{B_n}{n} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$. With this, we have as our final solution to the initial problem:

$$u(x,t) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}\sin(nx)\sin(nt)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! This helps a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. :)