# separable solution for the wave equation

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

given classical wave equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-b^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}=0, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1 .
$$

given also boundary conditions:

$$
u(0, t)=u(1, t)=0, \quad t>0
$$

and initial conditions:
$$
u(x, 0)=0.5 x(1-x), \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, 0)=0 \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1
$$

I want to show that analytical solution of the problem with b = 1 is:

$$
u(x, t)=\frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)] \cos (\pi n t) \sin (\pi n x)
$$

I don't understand, I want to use the integral, I don't understand where the use of the integral can help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you, is it okay now?

Comment: The solution process (involving a separable solution $u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$) is well covered in any engineering maths book, science book, pde book and countless posts on this site. Probably also in your course notes. Assuming you have looked at some of that you will need to be more specific about what you do not follow because, as you know, the solution process involves several steps. Your title is misleading too, the leapfrog scheme is a numerical method.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, this topic is not so clear to me.

Comment: This problem is similar with a full solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045512/find-the-solution-of-the-wave-equation-u-tt-u-xx-with-initial-conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the solution, in order to verify that at given $u(x,t)$ is indeed a solution, you have to individually verify that it satisfies :

1. the differential equation
2. the boundary conditions
3. the initial conditions

**1) The differential equation**

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial{t}^2} &= \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)](-\pi^2 n^2) \cos (\pi n t) \sin (\pi n x) \\
\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial{x}^2} &= \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)](-\pi^2 n^2) \cos (\pi n t) \sin (\pi n x) 
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial{t}^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial{x}^2} = 0$$

**2) The boundary conditions**

\begin{align}
u(0,t) &= \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)]\cos (\pi n t) \sin (0) = 0 \\
u(1,t) &= \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)] \cos (\pi n t) \sin (\pi n) = 0
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$$

**3) The initial conditions**

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial{t}}(x,0) = &= \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)](-\pi n )\sin (0) \sin (\pi n x) = 0
\end{align}

The tricky part consist of demonstrating that, for $0 < x < 1$,

$$u(x,0) = \frac{2}{\pi^{3}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}[1-\cos (\pi n)]\sin (\pi n x) = \frac{1}{2}x(1-x)$$

This can be demonstrated by verifying that their first and second derivatives of both sides are indeed equal

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}(x,0) = \frac{2}{\pi^{2}} &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}[1-\cos (\pi n)]\cos (\pi n x) = \frac{1}{2} - x \\
-\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}(x,0) = \frac{2}{\pi} &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}[1-\cos (\pi n)]\sin(\pi n x) = 1 
\end{align}

The second one is equivalent to show that,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1}\sin(\pi (2n+1) x) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

which by the way, a plot shows us, that is only true for $0 < x < 1$. This infinite Fourier series is well known, and you can find a demonstration of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057869/fx-sum-0-infty-frac-sin2n-1-x2n1-is-the-fourier-expansion-of-1).

That the second derivatives are equal does not imply by itself that that the function are equal, you also have to verify that the function and its first derivative are equal in one point, which you should be able to do.